# Structuring pd.DataFrame to filter columns based on metadata?

Tags: python, pandas

I have signals recorded by several instruments, as well as metadata giving information on the instruments themselves. Right now, I am storing data and metadata in different `pd.DataFrame`.

I want to be able to easily get the data produced by instruments matching some metadata-based criteria.

Here is a MWE of how I proceed:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections.abc import Sequence
from matplotlib.axes import Axes


def _sort_by(
        key: str,
        data: pd.DataFrame,
        metadata: pd.DataFrame,
        desired_values: Sequence[str]) -> pd.DataFrame | pd.Series:
    """Get instruments which ``key`` is in ``desired_values``."""
    assert key not in ('position', ), "Use `between` method for this keys."
    conds = metadata.loc[key].isin(desired_values)
    desired_columns = conds[conds].index
    desired_data = data[desired_columns]
    return desired_data


def plot_by_nature(data: pd.DataFrame,
                   metadata: pd.DataFrame,
                   to_plot: Sequence[str]
                   ) -> Axes:
    """Plot signals of desired instruments."""
    instruments_to_plot = _sort_by('nature', data, metadata, to_plot)
    instruments_gathered = [
        _sort_by('nature', data, metadata, [nature])
        for nature in to_plot]
    column_names_gathered = [instrument.columns
                             for instrument in instruments_gathered]
    axes = instruments_to_plot.plot(
        subplots=column_names_gathered,
        sharex=True)
    return axes


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df_data = pd.DataFrame(
        {'current1': np.linspace(0, 10, 11),
         'current2': np.linspace(0, 20, 11),
         'pressure1': np.linspace(-5, 5, 11),
         'temperature2': np.full(11, -4)}
    )
    df_metadata = pd.DataFrame(
        {'current1': ['current', 0.25],
         'current2': ['current', 0.5],
         'pressure1': ['pressure', 0.25],
         'temperature2': ['temperature', 0.5]},
        index=('nature', 'position')
    )
    to_plot = ('current', 'temperature')
    plot_by_nature(df_data, df_metadata, to_plot)
```

It works, but I have the feeling that I could do the same thing in a more concise and robust way.
Plus, what will happen when I will want to select instruments matching several conditions? For example, "plot only current and temperature probes, which position is higher than `0.4`"? Can I use the `groupby` methods? Should I use the [`attrs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.attrs.html)? [Subclass](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html) `pd.DataFrame`? Merge `df_data` with `df_metadata`? Switch to another library?

Comment: I am struggling to understand what the intention of data vs metadata is here. It looks like they contain similar information.

Comment: Why the use of `Sequence` and which part do you feel could be more efficient? Data subset with `df_data[df_metadata.columns[df_metadata.loc[key].isin(to_plot).values]]` (what you use) looks all right.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant: data holds a signal at different time steps. metadata is float or string that is related to the column, providing additional information. I could use `df_data_and_meta = pd.concat((df_data, df_metadata))`. Everything would be in the same dataframe. But I would have data of different type in a single column (seems like an anti-pattern?) and I cannot use the `df_data_and_metadata.plot` method.

Comment: @OCa:
`Sequence` to declare that several instruments with several `nature` can be plotted in the same call. Maybe a `*to_plot: str` would be more adapted?
I have the feeling that I am re-inventing methods that already exist. This stroke me when I found the existence of the `groupby` method, seemed like what I wanted but simpler. Anyway, if my MWE is ok, I will go on with this :)